# How to add event listners / signals to a simple superman class?

Tags: c++, oop, events, boost, event-handling

I can and would love to use boost or std for this. Sorry - I am new to C++. So I created a really simple program like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class superman
{
public:
  void punch(){cout << "superman: I hit the bad guy!" << endl;};
};

int main()
{
  superman clark;
  clark.punch();
  cin.get();
}
```

I want to add an event listner that would tell me when clark punched and cout something like "superman punched!". How to add such event listner and event function to my class?

Comment: `cout << "superman: I hit the bad guy!" << endl; ` doesn't return a `std::string` . Which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [boost::signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/signals.html) for that

you have to declare one class and overload her operator ()
after uoi have to bind the class on the signal, by using connect() method, and finally, use operator () of the signal

```
struct HelloWorld 
{
  void operator()() const 
  { 
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  } 
};

// ...

// Signal with no arguments and a void return value
boost::signal<void ()> sig;

// Connect a HelloWorld slot
HelloWorld hello;
sig.connect(hello);

// Call all of the slots
sig();
```

for using parameter in slot:

```
void print_sum(float x, float y)
{
  std::cout << "The sum is " << x+y << std::endl;
}

boost::signal<void (float, float)> sig;

sig.connect(&print_sum);

sig(5, 3);
```

Comment: I understand that it shall be done via signals bt I just do not see how to do it=(

Comment: you have look the tutorial? it's explain

Comment: i have add the example, with few comment